# Modifying data in a column Python

Tags: python, string

Hi guys i have a column like this,

```
 Start
 Start = 11122001
 Start = 12012014
 Start = 23122001
```

And i want to remove the "Start =" and the date format into

```
 Start
 11/12/2001
 12/01/2014
 23/12/2001
```

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

If you want to remove `Start =` from each line:

```
lines = [ format_date(re.sub("^Start =", '', line)) for line in lines ]
```

(presuming you have your text line by line in a list).

To format date you need to implement the function `format_date`
which will convert dates from `11122001` to `11/12/2001`.

There are several ways how to do this depending on the input format.
One of the solutions:

```
def format_date(x):
  if re.match(x, '[0-9]{8}'):
    return "/".join([x[:2], x[2:4], x[4:]])
  else:
    return x
```

You check first if the line match the date expression (looks like a date),
and if it does, rewrite it. Otherwise just return it as is.

Of course, you can combine the solution in one line
and don't use function at all, but in this case
it will be not so clear.

Another, `map`-based solution:

```
def format_line(x):
  x = re.sub("^Start =", '', line)
  if re.match(x, '[0-9]{8}'):
    return "/".join([x[:2], x[2:4], x[4:]])
  else:
    return x

map(format_line, lines)
```

Comment: Answer is incomplete. You should also mention, how to introduce `/` between numbers.

Comment: @niyasc: Fixed. Thank you for the comment